# Always getting Signature did not match. String to sign used was for Azure SAS token generation

Tags: java, azure, token

Following is my code. But it always throw an error for signature did not match. Not sure what is wrong with it? With Same URL if signature generated from azure portal, resource loads fine.

```
          String accessKey = "<API KEy from azure portal>";`your text`
          String accountName = "<My account name>";
          String signedPermissions = "rwdlacupiy"; 
      String signedService = "bfqt";  
      String signedResType = "o";  
     
      String signedIp = "";
      String protocol = "https";
      String  AZURE_API_VERSION = "2021-12-02";
      
      SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
        fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
        String start = fmt.format(cal.getTime());
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 4);
        String expiry1 =  fmt.format(cal.getTime());
      
     String stringToSign = ACCOUNT_NAME + "\n" +  
                  signedPermissions + "\n" +
                          signedService + "\n" +  
                          signedResType + "\n" +
                          start + "\n" +  
                          expiry1 + "\n" +  
                          signedIp + "\n" +  
                          protocol + "\n" +  
                           AZURE_API_VERSION+"\n";
          
     //System.out.println("string to sign "+ stringToSign);
     SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(accessKey),    "HmacSHA256");
        Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
        String  signature =  
                      Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256HMAC.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        //System.out.println("signature "+URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8"));
      String sasToken = "sv=" + AZURE_API_VERSION +
                "&ss=" + signedService +
                "&srt=" + signedResType +
                "&sp=" + signedPermissions +
                "&se=" + URLEncoder.encode(expiry1, "UTF-8")  +
                "&st=" + URLEncoder.encode(start, "UTF-8") +
                "&spr=" + protocol +
                "&sig=" + URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8") ;
      
      //System.out.println("sasToken1 "+sasToken);
      
      String resourceUrl="https://<accountName >.file.core.windows.net/<My resource path>";  // this is file resource
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(resourceUrl+"?"+sasToken);
        
            InputStream in =url.openStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`
```

Error is always 403 on the resource URL and if I place the URL in browser it is always
Signature did not match. String to sign used was 
rwdlacupiy
bfqt
o
2023-03-08T02:23:43Z
2023-03-12T01:23:43Z

https
2021-12-02

I tried above steps and not sure what is wrong. ACCESS key is copied from azure portal.
IF I generate SAS token from azure portal signature works but not with the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are using REST API version `2021-12-02`, your `stringToSign` should be constructed using the following logic:

```
StringToSign = accountname + "\n" +  
    signedpermissions + "\n" +  
    signedservice + "\n" +  
    signedresourcetype + "\n" +  
    signedstart + "\n" +  
    signedexpiry + "\n" +  
    signedIP + "\n" +  
    signedProtocol + "\n" +  
    signedversion + "\n" +
    signedEncryptionScope + "\n"
```

Please note `signedEncryptionScope` in the string to sign.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas#construct-the-signature-string

Comment: What should be value of this scope ? My setup is default and i see by default Microsoft-managed keys are selected.

Comment: Can you try with an empty string?

Comment: Empty string did not work. But when i add String signedEncryptionScope = "SharedKey";   it works.  Thank you so much for the guidance!!